# how to correctly MySQL "desc table" via java connectivity

Tags: java, mysql

I am actually building a project where the names of tables present in databases of mysql are displayed in a list in java.
user selects a table from a list and the description of that table in given using "desc tablename" command.
The problem is, it is supposed to get every field in table but it only gets first field. Below i have explained it more, but first heres my code-:

```
 try {
            int rowCount = tableModel.getRowCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                tableModel.removeRow(i);
            }
            String z = jList2.getSelectedValue().toString();
            try {
                Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                timeget();
                jTextArea4.append(now + ":   " + "/ Failed in getting Driver \n Error Message: " + e.getMessage() + " / \n \n");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
            }
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:" + GlobalParams.portvar + "/", "" + k, "" + j);
            stmnt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
            String query = "desc " + z;
            jTextArea5.append(now + ":   " + "/ desc " + z + "; / \n \n");
            ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery(query);
            String[] cnames = {"Field", "Type", "Null", "Key", "Extra"};
            tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(cnames);
            jTable1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
            jTable1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            if (rs.next()) {
                String field = rs.getString("Field");
                String type = rs.getString("type");
                String nullinfo = rs.getString("null");
                String key = rs.getString("key");
                String extra = rs.getString("extra");
                tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{field, type, nullinfo, key, extra});
            }
catch(SQLException e){//some blabla}
```

Now for detailing into problem->
Say from the list, i select a table called "city". Originally, it has four fields- ID, Name, Population, CountryCode. But in my jTable, only "ID" appears.

the code...

```
int rowCount = tableModel.getRowCount();
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
tableModel.removeRow(i);
}
```

...is simply to remove fields of old table when a new table is selected from list.
Hope i clarified my prob.

Please help regarding this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in this

```
if (rs.next()) {
                String field = rs.getString("Field");
                String type = rs.getString("type");
                String nullinfo = rs.getString("null");
                String key = rs.getString("key");
                String extra = rs.getString("extra");
                tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{field, type, nullinfo, key, extra});
            }
```

you are not continuing the loop

change the if loop to while loop

```
while(rs.next()) {
            String field = rs.getString("Field");
            String type = rs.getString("type");
            String nullinfo = rs.getString("null");
            String key = rs.getString("key");
            String extra = rs.getString("extra");
            tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{field, type, nullinfo, key, extra});
        }
```

Comment: :o My bad! Lol didn't notice it. Such a low mistake and it took me hours, feeling real bad :/ Thanks a lot for help though, you solved my prob :)